# JavaScript in microchips/embedded systems like robots/microwaves

Tags: javascript, hardware, embedded

Is there any product out on the market that uses JavaScript as the main language? For example a microwave that uses JavaScript, an embedded system that use JavaScript as their scripting language, a robot, a digital camera, etcetera. I know there’s a lot of server side JavaScript engines, but is there any home equipment? (I’m not referring to equipment like desktop computer, mobile, etcetera)

Answer (score 3):

Companies - over the long run - take the most profitable course of action when creating products, and using Javascript for appliances is not very profitable. Javascript does not intrinsically have the capability to interact with hardware on the level needed to control an appliance. Any attempt to use javascript for something like this would require a lower level language to already be on the system, and that lower level language would need a system to interpret javascript. This would require additional storage and computational power, not to mention that javascript itself would have to be heavily modified. It is more profitable to just use the lower level language directly (not to mention that it would have better performance).

I am sure that if javascript were used for appliances, there would be a jQuery function called $('#rocket').takeOff() which we could all use to go to the moon in a cross-browser compatible manner.

Answer (score 0):

There's a prototyping board from BeagleBoard called the [BeagleBone](http://beagleboard.org/bone) that ships with the Angstrom [Linux] Distribution, node.js, and Cloud9 IDE pre installed. It's designed to easily interface with motors, sensors, and cameras through gpio pins which can then be program via javascript and node.js.

For an interesting home product already using this board check out [Ninja Blocks](http://ninjablocks.com/).